# Close votes are to recommend closure flags, as reopen votes are to...what?

Tags: discussion, review

Those who have the "cast close and reopen votes" privilege can cast close and reopen votes to close and reopen questions.  For those who do not, they can raise recommended closure flags to close questions, but what could they do to reopen?

I've once posted a reopen request question on Music Stack Exchange Meta in order to have a question on Music Stack Exchange to be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the post so that the closure reason no longer applies.

- If it's too broad, narrow its scope
- If it's unclear, clarify it
- If it's a duplicate but the duplicate doesn't solve your problem, explain why that is so.
- If it's primarity opinion based, make it more concrete and factual.

Editing will push the post into the reopen queue as long as it's the first edit and was within five days of it getting closed, so make that first edit count.

Comment: Well answered, but it is not always appropriate to clarify what is in no way clear; nor to narrow its scope, when the OP hasn't done so in comments and "your guess" as an editor is no better than anyone else's guess; nor to change a primarily opinion based question unilaterally to something more concrete and factual, which may make the question the editor's question only.  Excellent advice for the OP of a closed question; great advice to a potential editor on questions that are on the boundary of "too broad/unclear/etc."